# Fancybox/JQuery in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, fancybox

We are using FancyBox 2.0/JQuery 1.7 in Internet Explorer 7 on http://www.tuxx.nl/spelling/werkwoorden/#print. When you click the 'Feedback' button at the bottom, you will see a popup box with scrollbars in it. How can we make it look like as it look like in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done in two steps:
1) <s>Set scrolling property to false</s>
2) Add the following somewhere in your code, AFTER any CSS setting your .wrapper class

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">#feedback_form .wrapper { height:362px; width:500px; }</style>
<![endif]-->
```

The way Fancybox sets the size of it's self according the the size of it's contents. In older versions of IE `$().width()` and `height` can return the wrong values, because it does not account for margin/padding, or some other reason. I use to know what the reason was, but I forgot. The main point is that it's broken in older IE's, so you need to set the width/height to something big enough for it to display right.

You can test this with `$('#feedback_form .wrapper').css({'height':'362px','width':'500px'});` somewhere in Javascript, as a proof of concept. I've personally tested it in IE9 compatibility mode, using the console before clicking the "feeback" button.

Answer (score 1):

Try set scrolling property to false. I found a answered question like yours, check it out [jQuery - Fancybox: But I don't want scrollbars!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268330/jquery-fancybox-but-i-dont-want-scrollbars)

Comment: Now I temporarely use `overflow: hidden`. Thanks for your answer!