# I want Fancybox to jump to anchor on close

Tags: fancybox, anchor, href

I am trying to get Fancybox to close and jump to a specific section anchor when when link is clicked within the fancybox ajax content. I have been trying several variations on this:

```
<a onclick="$.fancybox.close(); href="pricing">See pricing</a>
```

But every time I click the link it returns to the section anchor where it was initiated. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: why not give that section anchor an `id` and in link do like this `href="#pricing"`

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. The section does have an ID and the code should read
<a onclick="$.fancybox.close(); href="#pricing">See pricing</a>

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer supplied by Avinash at [how to prevent scrolling of page behind fancybox-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631124/how-to-prevent-scrolling-of-page-behind-fancybox-2)

I would thank him in comments but don't have enough points yet. If he reads this - Thanks :)