# How to set fixed width and height?

Tags: web, fancybox, dreamweaver

How to set fixed width and height on fancy box? the fancy box works fine but not the width/height.

The width should be 953px and the height 100%.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });

  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      padding : 0
  });

</script>
```

Comment: code:
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="about.html">about</a>

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Comment: the latest one fancyapps.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set width and height for fancy box directly :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'overlayShow': false,
    'frameWidth': 500, // set the width
    'frameHeight': 100, // set the height
    'type': 'iframe', // tell the script to create an iframe
    'autoDimensions':false,
    'autoSize':false
});
```

or

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    autoDimensions: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 400
});
```

Comment: it didn't work... the content inside the fancybox still scrolls around

Comment: this is another question. you want to remove scrollbars from modal window opened by fancy box ?

Comment: yeah at least the width so then it will be fixed

Comment: for remove scrolling you must set `scrolling: 'no',` in fancy box options and set this style for overlay : `overflow: hidden !important;` take a look at this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268330/jquery-fancybox-but-i-dont-want-scrollbars) for more info